# iPhone UISlider with two thumbs/indicators?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

Is anyone aware of a version of the iPhone UISlider control with two thumbs? I need a control that will allow specifying a range of values. The UISlider API docs would imply this isn't possible with the standard control, so I was wondering if anyone had a solution for this (or had solved it themselves).

Answer (score 7):

Here's a range slider I just cooked up

http://github.com/cmezak/CMRangeSlider

Comment: Hi, I looked at your code and I want to port it on the device and see how it works. Should I just use RangeSlider.h and RangeSlider.m? Can I intergrate these into my app and see how it works?

Comment: Your code cannot be compiled. It has a missing implementations of   ◦(void)setSuperRangeTrackImage:(UIImage *)image;
◦(void)setSubRangeTrackImage:(UIImage *)image; Please help.

Comment: Eek, sorry about that. just pushed some changes to github that fix this.

Comment: thanks! I'm trying to understand the code. Do you have a commented version which explains all the calculations and basic flow? btw, it's brilliant!:) I tried it on the device.

Comment: I tried your new code on the device. I wasn't able to move the thumbs at all.

Comment: Comment out line 24 in `AppDelegate_iPhone.m` (or change it to some value < 1.0). There is a typo in the value value for `slider.minimumRangeLength` which is casted to 3.0. With the whole range being only 1.0 wide, this results in the slider not being movable at all.

Comment: Very helpful. Seems like the track images are sideways by 90 degrees though. I only get the blue one stretching when I move it.

Answer (score 5):

If you're still interested this is my implementation. I'm making it well documented so everyone could start using it with ease.

https://github.com/fcy/fancy-ios/tree/master/src/ui/range-slider

It works with iOS 5+

Comment: This page does not exist anymore

Comment: Hi ingespor, I just updated the link to point to the correct location.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too. The way I solved it was a bit of a hack but simpler for noobs like me!

I put two sliders on top of eachother. Made the track of one invisible using a transparent .png file. Then created a sliderReleased: method that I linked to the touch up inside event in interface builder that switches the userInteractionEnabled: state of each slider.

It means that you can only set one slider at a time and you have to touch one before you can set the other but for my purposes it does the job.

I linked both sliders' touch up inside to this method and set tags to 1 and 2 and linked the value changed event to individual methods like normal.

```
-(IBAction) onReleaseBP: (id) sender {
if ([sender tag]==1) {
    [diastolicSld setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [systolicSld setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];     
}
else {
    [systolicSld setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [diastolicSld setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a range slider called DoubleSlide, it's not based on UISlider. But you can add images to make it look like one:

it's in here:
https://github.com/richy486/RACommon

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. One advantage versus other double-slider controls is that mine supports both setting up the control in code and in Interface Builder using IBDesignable/IBInspectable.

https://github.com/vermont42/JFADoubleSlider

Answer (score -1):

I'm not aware of a current one (ie. still in active development) but you could probably derive one by looking at the source of BWToolkit ( http://brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/ ).

There's an iTunes style slider implementation you could probably extend.

It's BSD licensed and the source is available from bitbucket.

Comment: BWToolkit is for the Mac, not the iPhone.