# Two position (start/end) user control

Tags: ios, controls

I have an application where I have a static amount of data available (let's say from 0 - 100). I would like to output this data starting from a variable position X (between 0 and 100) until another variable position (between X and 100).

iOS has a UISlider, but it only has the ability to define one position.

Is anyone aware of a control that could define both positions?

Answer (score 0):

`UIPickerView` with 2 components.

Comment: Thanks, but I have an 'infinite' number of selections between 0-100.  (which could be 0-10000, for example) I need to choose somewhere along the line for a start position (12.53798) and another selection farther down the line (89.2)

Answer (score 0):

This is something that you'll have to customize. This related SO post includes some good places to start: [iPhone UISlider with two thumbs/indicators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184185/iphone-uislider-with-two-thumbs-indicators)